# Getting the position of the current entry within its section

Tags: entries

I have a section of entries and I would like to output the position of the current entry to the entry template.

I have a code that was working in Craft 3 but it broke in Craft 4 and I am struggling to fix it...

This is my old code:

```
{% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('movementEpisodes').orderBy('postDate asc').ids() %}
{% set position = '' %}
{% for key, value in entryIds if value == entry.id %}
        {% set position = key + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
<h1>Material for the brain #{{ position }}</h1>
```

I am aware that it is not possible anymore to have an 'if' inside a 'for' loop.
What would be the correct way to do it in Craft 4?

I also tried another approach that didn't work but kept getting the number 1:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().section('movementEpisodes').orderBy('postDate').all() %}
{% set currentPosition = 0 %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.id == entry.id %}
        {% set currentPosition = loop.index %}
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<h1>Material for the brain #{{ currentPosition }}</h1>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a loop really, just use the `filter` filter, followed by the `keys` filter to do the same thing:

```twig
{% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('movementEpisodes').orderBy('postDate asc').ids() %}
<h1>Material for the brain #{{ entryIds|filter(item => item == entry.id)|keys[0] + 1 }}</h1>
```

Less really is more ;-)

Comment: Thank you! works perfect!